# mod_rewrite specific subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

From a Symfony setup, I have an `.htaccess` file that relays all requests to a PHP file using `mod_rewrite`.

Now I want one subdirectory to be treated separately: Requests to `/debug/...` should be relayed to a different PHP file.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post the code you used before.